# Nearest point projection in uniformly convex Banach spaces

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a [uniformly convex Banach space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_Banach_space), $x\in X$ and $C\subset X$ closed and convex, then there is a unique $y\in C$ with $$\lVert x-y\rVert=\inf_{z\in C}\lVert x-z \rVert.$$

Is there a good book where I can find a proof of this theorem?

Answer (score 4):

Theorem 8.2.2 of Larsen, "Functional Analysis", Marcel Dekker, 1973

Answer (score 1):

This is [Corollary 5.2.17](https://books.google.com/books?id=AwHrBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA453) in the book "An introduction to Banach space theory" by Megginson, where the term "uniformly rotund" is used instead of "uniformly convex".

For completeness, I sketch the proof.

1. We may assume $x=0$, by translation.
2. Let $d = \|y_n\|\to\inf \{\|y\| : y\in C\}$. We may replace $C$ with $\{y\in C: \|y\|\le 2d\}$ without changing the problem. This makes $C$ bounded.
3. Take a sequence $y_n $ such that $\|y_n\|\to d$.
4. Uniformly convex spaces are reflexive. Therefore, $C$ is weakly compact by Alaoglu's theorem.
5. Replace $\{y_n\}$ by a weakly convergent subsequence, and let $y$ be its limit. Note that $y\in C$ because closed convex sets are weakly closed. Hence $\|y\|\ge d$. But since closed  balls around $0$ are also weakly closed, we have $\|y\|\le d$. Thus $\|y\|=d$. This proves the existence.
6. For the uniqueness, strict convexity is enough: the midpoint of a line segment between two "nearest" points would be even closer to $0$.

Comment: does the strict convexity mean a stronger triangle inequality, namely $\|u+v\| < \|u\|+\|v\|$ whenever $v,u$ are linearly independent ?

Comment: and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784983/strict-subadditivity-of-the-norm-in-uniformly-convex-banach-spaces and  wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Normed_vector_space  seems to approve what I wrote.

Comment: This is way too overloaded of theorems. The proof in Larsen's book as cited by Siminore seems the best choice of them all.